# Is there a way to link to a specific card in Trello?

Tags: trello

If i'm im'ing or tweeting with another team member about a trello card, is there a way for me to say 'Hey look at this card: http://trello/123xyz' so that they can go directly to the card (assuming they are a member of the board, etc) -- rather than asking them to go find the card based on assignment and search for the title?

Answer (score 10):

Now there's a "Share, Print and Export" link on each card which provides a shorter URL to the card which is not tied to the board it's currently on.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. When you click on a card and it opens, you can just copy the URL.

The URLs are very long,but they do work, e.g.

https://trello.com/card/board/short-ids-for-cards/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e8cc51805ee52899defd443

(Note to potential editors: I've deliberately not used Link syntax here, in order to make it obvious what the URL looks like!)

**Update 20/10/2012**

Note that as the URL contains the board name, the URL will stop working if you move the card to a different board (which was probably not possible when this question was asked).

Comment: This answer is wrong. If the card is moved between boards, this link no longer works.

Comment: @Lombo I've added a note pointing out this limitation - but I feel that the answer does remain a way to get a link to a particular card.

Comment: The limitation with the URL containing the board name isn't present with the link that can be found on the card's ```More...``` menu. That is a global unique link to the card, even if it is moved to another board.

Answer (score 6):

There's now a 'More...' link at the bottom right of the card. Clicking this opens a pop-up which includes a short 'Link to this card' URL. (I suspect this was previously the 'Share, Print and Export' link mentioned by Josh Metcalfe in his answer.)

Comment: Indeed, and that link seems to be globally unique, also if the card is move to another board in the mean time.

Answer (score 2):

There's a link called 'More...' in the lower right corner of the card.

Under that, there's a shareable link to the card. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to link to a card by its number you can use:

```
https://trello.com/c/{short-id-for-board}/{card number}
```

Comment: I wish, this doesnt work

Comment: However that is the link pattern for a card URL, the placeholder name is wrong.
{short-id-for-board} place holder is wrong, because it is not a "board ID", it is a global ID of the card.

{card number} is a unique ID of the card INSIDE the the board.
This one is optional in the URL.

`https://trello.com/c/{global-card-id}` is also works

Answer (score 1):

I discovered by trying that you can use

> trello.com/c/longCardId

and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, just typing in a hash followed by the card ID works - Trello links it automatically to the correct card within the same board. You can find out what the card number is under "Share and more..." in the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple extension for Chrome which adds a "Short URL" button to the Actions menu, allowing you to one-click copy the short URL to your clipboard.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-short-url/kknbnjdfmclblpjkedhjfbbkgjomciga

It's open source and I'd appreciate any issues or Pull Requests people fancy doing to make it better! :)

https://github.com/njt1982/TrelloShortUrl

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Share the Trello card number ('Card #1117'). By entering the number into search box, your colleague will immediately open the card.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your browser to open a new tab (at least in my experience with Chrome), you can get rid of the protocol and hostname from the link, as follows:

```
[link text](/c/{shortBoardId}/{cardId})
```

Also, using the board-independent link (as suggested in other answers) has the unfortunate consequence of redirecting the browser. Hitting the back button then immediately redirects the browser again. To return the the original place from which you linked, you need to go two steps back in the history. This is not the case with the link.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat important annoying problem to *easily* reference cards *without* a unique card hash. For example, enabling power-ups like [Card Numbers by Reenhanced](https://trello.com/power-ups/59c3d177178a761767b49278/card-numbers-by-reenhanced) will always show the internal card number on the board:

[image]

Unfortunately, a unique link to a card by its number (i.e., `https://trello.com/b/[board-id]/[card-num]` is impossible (unlike JIRA where this exists (i.e., using the `/browse/[card-id]` link).

As a workaround, you can use Trello's `/search` endpoint instead.

```
https://trello.com/search?q=[card-num]%20board%3A[board-id]
```

This returns a page of results - one additional click to get to the card directly, but is currently the only workaround I can think of.

[image]

My team uses [GitHub AutoLink references](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/autolinked-references-and-urls#custom-autolinks-to-external-resources) to reference our Trello cards on GitHub PRs, issues etc. So setting up an autolink reference here is useful when you want to refer to a specific card number (not a hash):

[image]

It's not perfect, but it works for now!